# Jquery Literal Pattern Uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery

i'm learning to avoid a spaghetti code a try the Literal Pattern in Jquery.
my code is:

```
<div id="container">
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <input placeholder="name" type="text">
    <ul>

    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var myObj = {
        people: ['Will', 'Peter'],
        init: function() {
            myObj.cacheDom();
            myObj.bindEvents();
            myObj.showPerson();
            myObj.renderPerson();
        },
        cacheDom: function() {
            this.$el = $('#container');
            this.$button = this.$el.find('button');
            this.$input = this.$el.find('input');
            this.$ul = this.$el.find('ul');
        },
        bindEvents: function() {
            this.$button.on('click', this.addPerson.bind(this));
        },
        renderPerson: function() {
            var data = this.people;
            $.each(data, function(value){
                this.$ul.append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
            });
        },
        addPerson: function() {
            this.people.push(this.$input.val());
            // this.renderPerson();
            this.$input.val('');
            // this.showPerson();
        },
        showPerson: function() {
            console.log(this.people);
        }

    };

    myObj.init();

</script>
```

i just want to iterate with the each iterator over my people array and append it to the list but i'm getting an

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of undefined at
>   String.

i don't understand why do i get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the display and add person working

```js
var myObj = {
  // to be init later
  $el: '',
  $button: '',
  $input: '',
  $ul: '',

  people: ['Will', 'Peter'],
  init: function() {
    this.cacheDom();
    this.bindEvents();
    this.showPerson();
    this.renderPerson();
  },
  cacheDom: function() {
    this.$el = $('#container');
    this.$button = this.$el.find('button');
    this.$input = this.$el.find('input');
    this.$ul = this.$el.find('ul');
  },
  bindEvents: function() {
    this.$button.on('click', this.addPerson.bind(this));
  },
  renderPerson: function() {
    var data = this.people;
    var list = [];
    $.each(data, function(index) {
      list.push('<li>' + data[index] + '</li>');
    });
    this.$ul.html(list.join(''));
  },
  addPerson: function() {
    this.people.push(this.$input.val());
    this.renderPerson();
    this.$input.val('');
    this.showPerson();
  },
  showPerson: function() {
    console.log(this.people);
  }

};

myObj.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
  <input placeholder="name" type="text">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is mostly Greg's code but with few improvements (including yours scope hint)

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your variables like below:-

Working example:-

```js
var myObj = {
    el :'',
    button :'',
    input:'',
    ul:'',
    people: ['Will', 'Peter'],
    init: function() {
        myObj.cacheDom();
        myObj.bindEvents();
        myObj.showPerson();
        myObj.renderPerson();
    },
    cacheDom: function() {
        el = $('#container'); //assign values to variables
        button = el.find('button');
        input = el.find('input');
        ul = el.find('ul');
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        button.on('click', this.addPerson.bind(this));
    },
    renderPerson: function() {
        var data = this.people;
        $.each(data, function(key,value){
            ul.append('<li>' + value + '</li>'); //use variables
        });
    },
    addPerson: function() {
        this.people.push(input.val());
        ul.html(''); //remove ul html first
        input.val('');
        this.renderPerson(); // call function again to append whole array data to ul
    },
    showPerson: function() {
        console.log(this.people);
    }

};

myObj.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
 <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
 <input placeholder="name" type="text">
 <ul>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: is not working with your solution: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this

Comment: @GregOstry Can you create an example link so that we can check and rectify?

Comment: cool that works. but im wondering why is this not working with ´this´

Comment: but when i make global variable,than this is not safe and consume unnecessary rescource ?